# doctrine how to fetch database switch a datetime

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine

I can't find the answer in the documentation.
I use symfony for an application, i have a database with a datetime for each of my table and would like to get only the row with the most recent datetime is there a function like `$repository->findOneById($id)` to obtain this object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using QueryBuilder:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->orderBy('p.datetime', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getQuery();

$product = $query->getResult();
```

Regards.

Comment: Hope I got it right since the title of your question makes me doubt regarding the rest of your message.

Comment: This was my interpretation also. I think your answer is on point.

Comment: I don't test it yet but it seems a good solution, I just thought it was possible without the QueryBuilder, but thanks.

Comment: Maybe a little bit more sexy without querybuilder: $repository->findBy(array(), array('datetime' => 'desc'),1,0); where datetime is your datetime attribute name (not tested).